# Are these two graphs different?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I was expecting these graphs to be the same.

```
g1 = AdjacencyGraph[{{0}}];
g2 = CanonicalGraph[g1];
```

`FullForm` suggests that they are

```
FullForm[g1]
(* Graph[List[1],List[]] *)

FullForm[g2]
 (* Graph[List[1],List[]] *)
```

But equality `==` (or `===`) says they are not.

```
g1 == g2
(* False *)
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

```
$Version
(* "12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)
```

Comment: You consider a degenerate case. In general, as the documentation says, a graph `g` and `CanonicalGraph[g]` are not the same, but isomorhic: `IsomorphicGraphQ[g1,g2]` performs `True`. Maybe, `==` and `===` produce  generic answers.

Comment: Really weird. You can type `g1 === g2`, then highlight `g1`, press command+enter (evaluate in place), then do the same to `g2`—the result will be `True` instead of `False`. (The same works with copying the rhs's of their `Definition`s.) I think this goes beyond degeneracy.

Comment: @thorimur: Can you ground your statenent " I think this goes beyond degeneracy"?

Comment: @user64494 I did already, I think? How does degeneracy account for the behavior I described?

Comment: Yes, it is a major issue that the meaning of `SameQ` is not documented for `Graph`, and that it depends on internal representation that is not observable. I raised this issue with WRI more than once, but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: @thrimur: You describe some trick with keys, no more and no less.

Comment: @user64494 I'm not sure what you mean by this. (You can evaluate in place without key presses.) Further, I don't think degeneracy accounts for the behavior I described. I believe the issue is what Szabolcs said.

Comment: @Szabolcs Interesting. Do you happen to know by what mechanism the internal representations manage to agree after evaluation-in-place, but not during standard evaluation? (Or where exactly these internal representations are "stored"?) That's really weird to me.

Comment: @thorimur `Graph` is atomic (`AtomQ`). This means that its "FullForm" doesn't truly reflect what it is, as with usual non-atomic expressions. Despite this, many atomic types still have a full form, for the purpose of serialization. This allows them to be sent through MathLink (WSTP), which is necessary for parallelization, to store them in an .m file, to `Compress` them, etc. But note that this "full form" is not really what they are: it is merely a serialized representation that they can be converted to and from.

Comment: @thorimur What happens when you evaluate in-place is that the expression gets serialized (so that it can be stored in a notebook cell), then after your second evaluation it will be converted back to an atomic graph.

Comment: The fact that this cycling through a "full form" changes how the expression behaves is obviously a bug. There are other such bugs too. I have been complaining about them for years, yet no fix. A typical one is this: `Graph[KaryTree[4], VertexSize -> Large]` does not work, but `Graph[Uncompress@Compress@KaryTree[4], VertexSize -> Large]` does. Here I used Compress/Uncompress to serialize/deserialize the Graph, but any other method would have done the same, including the in-place evaluation you used.

Comment: @Szabolcs I see. So this is why `g1 === g1` gives `False` after evaluating-in-place just one of the `g1`'s—the evaluated-in-place version is evaluated (and serialized) for a *notebook*, and would not be evaluated that same way during standard evaluation. Is that right?

Comment: (By the way, @Szabolcs, I'd think your comments are sufficiently illuminating to constitute a full answer to this question!)

Answer (score 2):

With my current version

```
$Version
(* "13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)
```

I now have (as I would have expected)

```
g1 = AdjacencyGraph[{{0}}];
g2 = CanonicalGraph[g1];

g1 == g2
(* True *)
```

and

```
g1 === g2
(* True *)
```